# knex.js join two subqueries (nested queries)

Tags: knex.js

I want to join two subqueries in knex.js and produce this sql result.

```
SELECT '*'
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        `*`
    FROM
        `A`
    WHERE
        A.id = 1
) AS `t1`
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `B`
    WHERE
       B.id = 2
) AS `t2`
ON
    `t1`.`c` = `t2`.`d`
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use this code :

```
knex
        .select('*')
        .from(function () {
            this.select('*').from('A')
                .where('id',1)
                .as('t1');
        })
        .leftJoin(
            knex('B').where('id',2).as('t2')
            , function () {
                this.on('t1.c', '=', 't2.d');
            })
```

Answer (score 14):

```
knex(
  knex('A').where('A.id',1).as('t1')
).leftJoin(
  knex('B').where('B.id', 2).as('t2'), 
  't1.c', 
  't2.d'
)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: There are like 1000 this kind of questions about making some specific queries in knex, so I have stopped from explaining how knex works while answering those. For people using knex this kind of usage examples are self explanatory. Like ”huh  I didnt knew I can pass query builder there!”

Comment: Note that the place of the `.as('t1')` is important - my query was getting screwed up because I mistakenly put the `.as('t1')` _right before_ the `.leftJoin(...` outside of the first set of parentheses instead of _right after_ the `.where('A.id',1)`.